# Почему после struct, union, class нужно ставить точку с запятой, а после функций - нет?

Tags: c++, c

Почему после `struct, union, class` нужно ставить точку с запятой, а после функций - нет?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю, что потому, что это объявление типа, которое может быть - без точки с запятой - началом объявления переменной, функции и так далее.

Например,

```
struct A { int a; } a;
```

или

```
struct A { int a; } b(int с);
```

Точка с запятой четко ограничивает и отделяет объявление типа.